# "Get got" or "Get Gotten" which is correct?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms, american-english, british-english, slang

I've heard both usages in the meaning "**to get caught**", however, I'm not sure that both of them are correct.

From my research, though, both should be fine, however, "**got**" is both Br.E and Am.E, while "**gotten**" is only Am.E, because:

> In **American English**, the past participle of “**get**” in its literal sense of “**receive**” or “**become**” is usually “**gotten**”.

There another interesting thing about "**get got**" vs "**get gotten**". That is, when we use them in the *Past Perfect tense* the "**gotten**" version is preferred due to the doubling of "**got**". I can't say for sure about the *Present Perfect* or the *Future Perfect* since I've never met either of them used in these tenses.

- He had got gotten (not *got got*) yesterday by the police.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question is but 'got gotten' in the sense of "He had got gotten yesterday by the police," is enormously rare and I've never heard it spoken.  It only appears 110,000 times in Google and in almost all of those cases it is 'got/gotten', not 'got gotten'.

Answer (score 1):

In Australian English, particularly Sydney street/jail slang, it definitely means something very different; if Mr White got got for his crimes, then Mr White would be bleeding to death on a prison yard somewhere. Full of puncture wounds, probably also badly bruised.  And nobody saw a thing.

Comment: Just curious, does it _specifically_ mean what you've suggested? Puncture wounds in a prison yard? Or is this just a bit of imagination, and it broadly means something like _to be killed_? Might be helpful to learners if you clarify. You can [edit] your post at any time.